# Convert a datetame object to the correct date (MM-DD-YYYY to DD-MM-YYYY)

Tags: python, datetime

I have parsed a date and stored it as a datetime object. The date was written in the format MM-DD-YYYY instead of DD-MM-YYYY when it was parsed. What would be the easiest way to convert the object to the correct date?

Comment: And you cannot simply parse it again using the right format? You can just use `dt.replace(month=dt.day, day=dt.month)` to create a new object with those two components swapped.

Comment: Worked well. I was unsure about how o use the replace method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can swap out values with the [`datetime.datetime.replace()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace), provided the `day` value is within the range 1-12, of course:

```
dt = dt.replace(month=dt.day, day=dt.month)
```

The method returns a *new* `datetime` instance.

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dt = datetime(2015, 2, 11)
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 11, 0, 0)
>>> dt.replace(month=dt.day, day=dt.month)
datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 2, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.datetime.strptime('2011-06-09', '%Y-%m-%d')
>>> d.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
'09-06-2011'
```

*Not working? Let me know :)*